# What is the definition of a Kuntres?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, jewish-books

A kuntres is, generally speaking, known to be a pamphlet or a booklet in the spirit and style of traditional ethical Torah teachings. But how is this different to a small sefer? How many pages it contains (or should contain)? Is there some kind of guidelines about what a kuntres is or a clear definition to it?

Comment: How is a booklet different from a small book?  How is a booklet different from a pamphlet for that matter?  I would suggest that while there might be a demarcation in formal settings, the original and informal uses don't have or need well defined parameters.